# Subversion: Hide issue number text box on sub folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I right click in `C:\LoansPQ2\Website` and choose commit, I want to see the issue number text box . It's already implemented as the figure below shows.

[image: I want to see the issue number text box when I'm in the root folder]

However, when I right click in `C:\LoansPQ2\Website\Consumer\v2` and commit, I don't want to see the issue number text box

[image: I don't want to see the issue number text box when I'm in a sub folder]

How could I achieve that?

Comment: What issue tracker do you use?

Comment: @mkiever how is it related to issue tracker?

Comment: @mkiever I rephrazed the question. I want to change subversion instead of issue tracker.

Comment: Still not sure what you want. I do not understand what this issue tracker has to do with your svn repository. Do you look for svn ignore files? Look for them in svn documentation.

Comment: @mkiever I uploaded pictures with the real example. Hopefully you can understand my problem.

Comment: Added Tortoisesvn tag (awaiting peer review). Maybe then someone knowledgable can find it. You should rewrite: This is about Tortoisesvn (not svn) and about the displayed Bugzilla ID (not "issue tracker").

Comment: Read the documentation https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html

Comment: @bahrep Did you find how to disable this feature for a folder "TortoiseSVN will search upwards through the folder tree to find them until it comes to an unversioned folder, or the tree root (e.g. C:\) is found"?